# Upload an existing .env file to Google Cloud Secret Manager

Tags: node.js, gcloud, google-secret-manager

I'm trying out Google Cloud Secret Manager for the first time.

My intention is to store all the contents of my `.env` file in Secret Manager and access any of them at will from any of my Cloud Run Services.

Is there no way to upload the contents of my `.env` file to Secret Manager?

The process of specifying *KEY1=VALUE1,KEY2=VALUE2* is too tedious for me and not good at all.

I already have an `.env` file, I just need a `gcloud` command I can run in my terminal to export the contents of that `.env` file to Secret Manager.

Any ideas on this will really suffice.

Comment: The documentation is comprehensive and includes instructions for adding a file as a [secret version](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#add-secret-version)

Comment: I've seen it in the docs. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately used a python script to upsert secrets from my .env files.  Here call `upsert_secret` with your project_id and `.env` file path.

I added these dependencies to my requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.15.1
google-crc32c==1.5.0 
python-dotenv==0.21.0
```

Upsert Google Cloud Secrets Script

```py
import contextlib
from typing import Optional

import google_crc32c
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from google.api_core.exceptions import AlreadyExists
from google.cloud import secretmanager


def add_secret_version(client, project_id, secret_id, payload):
    """
    Add a new secret version to the given secret with the provided payload.
    """

    # Build the resource name of the parent secret.
    parent = client.secret_path(project_id, secret_id)

    # Convert the string payload into a bytes. This step can be omitted if you
    # pass in bytes instead of a str for the payload argument.
    if isinstance(payload, str):
        payload = payload.encode("UTF-8")

    # Calculate payload checksum. Passing a checksum in add-version request
    # is optional.
    crc32c = google_crc32c.Checksum()
    crc32c.update(payload)

    # Add the secret version.
    response = client.add_secret_version(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "payload": {"data": payload, "data_crc32c": int(crc32c.hexdigest(), 16)},
        }
    )

    # Print the new secret version name.
    print(f"Added secret version: {response.name}")


def upsert_secret(project_id: str, dotenv_path: Optional[str] = ".env"):
    """Modified from
    https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-create-secret-python
    """
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    for secret_id, secret_value in dotenv_values(dotenv_path).items():
        # Create the secret.
        with contextlib.suppress(AlreadyExists):
            response = client.create_secret(
                request={
                    "parent": f"projects/{project_id}",
                    "secret_id": secret_id,
                    "secret": {"replication": {"automatic": {}}},
                }
            )
            print(f"Created secret: {response.name}")
        # Set Value
        add_secret_version(client, project_id, secret_id, secret_value)
```